# Flutter : Cannot display image from image url firestore

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I try display data from firestore using image url. i use FutureBuilder for get my image url value from firestore. but i have problem because my image cannot display and show red screen. i got messages in my debug console like :

> Another exception was thrown: A build function returned null.
>
> I/flutter (13506): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError:
>   The method '[]' was called on null.
>
> I/flutter (13506): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError:
>   Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance method '[]'

and this my code :

```
ListTile(
  leading: new FutureBuilder(
    future: Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('uid', isEqualTo: _post['imgurl']).getDocuments(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
      if(snapshot.hasData){
        if(snapshot.data != null){
          print(snapshot.data['imgurl']);
          return CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snapshot.data['imgurl']),
          );
        }
      }
    },
  ),
  title: Text('Richard');
)
```

can you tell me where is my fault?

Comment: can you database image sniped(cropped image).so after this.its easy to understand your code mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Future` returns a list of documents, not just one. You're trying to get a document's `imageUrl` from a list of `document` and not from one.

Your `snapshot.data` is a list of documents, you can find them in `snapshot.data.documents`.

If you're interested in just one document,  I suggest you to change your `Future` to something that returns only one document (e.g. getting the first).

If you want to keep your `Future` as it is, just get the first document from your `snapshot.data` and do your work on it.

At this moment I can't provide further examples, since I'm not able to do it logistically (I'm not at home), but could provide you some if my suggestions do not help you resolve!

Comment: yeah, thanks! I have tried that.. but why always show message like this : 

Another exception was thrown: A build function returned null. 
Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Image.network(widget.snapshot.data['imgurl'])
```

Here is how I handled the problem:

```
Card(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
                              elevation: 8.0,
                              child:
                              Image.network(
                                widget.ds.data['GraphImg'],
                                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                              ),                           )
```

worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
width: 50.0,
height: 50.0,
fit: BoxFit.cover,
image:ContentThumbnail.thumbnails[index],
placeholder: 'images/placeholder.jpg',),),
```

Comment: FadeInImage is the best for loading network image because of the placeholder which will show first until the right image is displayed